# How i prevent dbclick event on vegalite chart

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

I create a chart in vegalite and make a scroller (vconcat-1) that look like a scroller for large data .
issue is that when i double click on scroller(vconcat-1) then chart render with whole , i did not want that, is there any way to stop dbclick event on chart canvas of vegalite chart by using js or vegalite can handle this by specs.
note- plz dont stop single click on chart
[editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMJsGszGgBMARgAMlAGwAWJQjn00IAFJJZ-HaKILJICHDeACIASiYgAL4KpuaWaLYA7ACclJli7p4w3gBicEyBtsGh4d4A6gCi0QlJIGYWVqi2YhIuABz5loXoALJIAE7llWER6ADiABI+TcltNgDMjunW-V7oAII440FKVdMgACpzdUstKe22TumU1unbgyAjAJ4Tx1PePgCqAE1rq1UqhVhJ7FsQB4Bn8LN8Qr90HVInFEsswdZVi4ci8YQV4YJESdvABFADKkRBtzS6ScT1e3l2DDIJORIF2AA10c1QXcnKtKD03AS4egKXAcOzqugipEKTSVh1MrZKPZbEz0AB5KCYGWnXZUpVg2w9aw5TJakAAOTYxAN3guNpNd1s2Sy1sicCgjvQ0SKADVXWlrLj0qLYTtfP5AtZJrKQDUKVyQ6gw2qen0xdGSmVrPGfonKbs0-chRrrSNDoWkYmANLagCSZdWj1W1v2NYTp0BcxdGJuyvsVaQXwLPe8fcWg-5aScjjEmpzbx8CInRdO9YAMtqEgBdRIgTCjfwQABmbFGCCMoAA7jRZMo2HfbyA2DhvKMXwB9WQMBAmDgUZgiQAx0G-V94kPfclGUfQoFGGgcEwdh5FmNg2DIQQ4AAcggAACCBMDYKAAGsCIOGgoDgAj7WAgjUPCShgmIKA5CgNQ33gGgyCwGwxBHEBBDHYC3zgWR2OUR8yDQUAAA85JAc8aDgQRlG8KNCiUTAPhwU5ZDYBBHx0YIZFGdpQBUtSNIgl9giveCQPQMCaKfGSEiPD4lOs9TvDnJRoB0aZQAAL2Atg0HPHQIDgI9dP07wAEcGH8VD1FQ0hPPcMYyKU4RZGmE89CUHA2EfdpirgHTMMEVDP1QKqdL004xjgFB4mgnTT1kC8rxvVBjGUmg6rEzQQBwMYwm8JhRgYCBCk62CQAfZRo3YywkEfMTBwkqSPPG9jBCvJTtF0U5hD4zAZlPbyj0U8akHkmhwNAESgMEcDos+6rj2osivpi370pwtB-0EQQj182yV2CBKDKMkzBDMq9LOGmyv3spRHLGkBXIk6TZFkzqlG88bof82lAs40HxvC78oqB+KWuS1LLDoNQaCykmMDgXj+NQFwhOQUY8vGj8kCgOgyeXeHvDajrSqmhBwKG0l0Fm+btJAWKcL1JS9rYQmyFVkBFOWk8zxEzAirm4GWfQCrgLOzzltW9bPC2wqQOg+IgA)

Comment: Where is your sample spec?

Comment: hii davide, question has been pdated with sample specs, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need clear:false.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Count": 210.64, "month": "Jan-21", "name": "DRC"},
      {"Count": 179.95, "month": "Feb-21", "name": "WER"},
      {"Count": 155.48, "month": "Mar-21", "name": "GHJ"},
      {"Count": 230.72, "month": "Apr-21", "name": "THE"},
      {"Count": 167.27, "month": "May-21", "name": "JUY"},
      {"Count": 35.02, "month": "Jun-21", "name": "EDC"},
      {"Count": 234.97, "month": "Jul-21", "name": "QSD"},
      {"Count": 176.2, "month": "Aug-21", "name": "AXC"},
      {"Count": 163.84, "month": "Sep-21", "name": "FDS"},
      {"Count": 191.01, "month": "Oct-21", "name": "ASD"},
      {"Count": 182.99, "month": "Nov-21", "name": "THN"},
      {"Count": 119.79, "month": "Dec-21", "name": "RFV"},
      {"Count": 124.74, "month": "Jan-22", "name": "WSX"},
      {"Count": 241.88, "month": "Feb-22", "name": "QSA"},
      {"Count": 163.01, "month": "Mar-22", "name": "KOI"},
      {"Count": 137.3, "month": "Apr-22", "name": "YHN"},
      {"Count": 0, "month": "May-22", "name": "YHJ"},
      {"Count": 160.51, "month": "Jun-22", "name": "KLO"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "row"}]}],
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "height": 250,
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "month",
              "type": "nominal",
              "sort": {"field": "row", "order": "ascending"}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Count",
              "scale": {"zero": false},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          },
          "mark": {"line": true, "point": true, "tooltip": true, "type": "area"}
        }
      ],
      "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
      "width": "container"
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "lightGray"},
        "x": {
          "axis": {"labels": false, "ticks": false, "title": null},
          "field": "month",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": {"field": "row", "order": "ascending"}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Count",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "height": 40,
      "mark": {"opacity": 1, "type": "area"},
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {
            "encodings": ["x"],
            "translate": true,
            "type": "interval",
            "clear": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "width": "container"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it not as i am looking for , i want double click should be stop on any where on vegalite chart canvas

Comment: You need to use Vega for that.

Comment: can u help me to add a simple fixed scroll in vegalite

Comment: What do you mean? Can you supply more details about what you want?